# Cypress login with google account don't work when i run my tests

Tags: google-oauth, cypress

I am using cypress for end-to-end testing. I have to login to the app using google account.
I follow documentation of Cypress to use the third-party authentication API to login with google account. all works fine when I do cypress open to excute my scrpit but have trouble and my test fail when i do cypress run . I cannot access google's login form with cypress google doesn't allow bot to login.
Please help me with this

To login with google account i use :

```
Cypress.Commands.add("loginByGoogleApi", () => {

 
    cy.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
        body: {
            grant_type: "refresh_token",
            client_id: Cypress.env("client_id"),
            client_secret: Cypress.env("client_secret"),
            refresh_token: Cypress.env("refresh_token"),
        },
    }).then(({ body }) => {
        const { access_token, id_token } = body;

        cy.request({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}` },
        }).then(({ body }) => {
            cy.log(body);
            const userItem = {
                token: id_token,
                user: {
                    googleId: body.sub,
                    email: body.email,
                    givenName: body.given_name,
                    familyName: body.family_name,
                    imageUrl: body.picture,
                },
            };

            window.localStorage.setItem("googleCypress", JSON.stringify(userItem));
        });
    });
});
```

I get this error when I do cypress run

[image]

Comment: Were you able to get past this issue? Currently facing this issue as well.

Comment: get this answor on Cypress Discord channel unfortunately : "Your Cypress tests are going to fail using the run commands because of the way Google does their 2FA. As far as I know, there is not a workaround for authenticating with Google, Okta or MS in a headless browser. I'm very happy to be wrong on this as well if anyone else has better insight"
for now we don't find workaround